# HBase different clients

Tags: hbase, thrift, avro

I am working on a project where I would like to read the data from the HBase system. I read that there are various HBase clients available, the default Java Client, Thrift, Avro, etc.

Now I am confused if I choose the default Java Client then would I be able to read the data which is stored in the HBase using the thrift client?

I wanted to understand that if I use the thrift client to read the data from HBase then it will use the thrift de-serializer to convert data from binary type to appropriate type? If that is true then data loaded using the thrift client will be corrupted if I read using the HBase default client?

Thanks for your help!!
~Rohit

Comment: Guyz Please let me know if you have any question with understanding the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are developing your HBase application in Java, I recommend using the raw HBase API - that is more powerful than Thrift, REST, Avro, etc.

The Java HBase API communicates directly with the HBase database through the Zookeepers.

If you are *not* using Java, then you have to go with one of the other protocols - Thrift, REST, Avro, etc. For example, Python has some libraries for Thrift (I recommend HappyBase) as well as REST. So do Ruby and other languages.

If you insert data using the Java API (directly), you will be able to retrieve the exact same data using Thrift on Python or Ruby. You might want to be careful with the data structure/format (HBase stores everything as bytes) so just be careful storing strings, ints, unicode strings, etc.

Comment: Thanks Suman. Its really helpful!!                                 So just to be clear and make sure I understand you correctly. Thrift client interface doesn't use the thrift serialization/deserialization it uses the same mechanism for serialization and deserialization which HBase Java client uses?

Comment: Just to continue my last question, even the HBase commmand line client will be using the exact same serialization mechanism when I try to insert a int and then it gets converted in to the binary?

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting question - I haven't played around with the serialization part? Are you inserting just ints/strings or full objects?

Comment: I recommend experimenting with it and seeing - that's how I had to figure out the best way to write/read ints, strings, unicode, etc. In general, if you write something to HBase, you will get exactly the same thing as output.

Comment: hmm I will try to play and see what happens. Anyways I was looking for just primitive java types, strings, int, etc. Thanks Again!

Comment: OK, then I definitely recommend just writing ints/strings into HBase, and reading them out to see what you get. I suspect that the Thrift serialization/de-serialization does NOT affect what you write/read.